# Create Mac shortcut with a modifier key and a mouse button

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts

I would like to be able to use the "Mission Control > Move left/right a space" commands by hitting Ctrl + the back/forward buttons on my mouse (it's not a Magic Mouse).  The default keyboard shortcut is Ctrl + Left Arrow/Right Arrow, and I don't see any way to change it...

Comment: Hello @Eric. I want the same. Did you manage to achieve this?

Comment: Unfortunately no...